# magento 2: create custom frontend input type

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, eav

I need a custom frontend input type which I would call "table":

[image]

The issue at hand is that I have a customer that has a lot of different attribute sets with even more attributes. And he is in a constant need for more. Alls this only to describe the products in a tabular way. Giving him a html editor to create html tables is an absolute no go. This has been tried and the results were horrible (an unfixable html mess).

So my idea is to create ONE attribute (varchar) that gives the user a simple interface with x columns (to be defined) and an undefined number of rows. The user should be able to dynamically (javascript) add new rows as needed. The result should be json encoded and saved in one varchar field.

I picture the frontend a little bit like the customer group price:

[image]

I hope there is someone smarter than me that could point me into the right direction on how to go about this. I know all about creating modules and using plugins and so on. But this is a little bit beyond my skill so far.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have this exact challenge.

Comment: I ended up buying this: https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-product-attributes-table/